# Why is my CTE faster than one part of itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I created a CTE in SQL Server today that is really baffling me. It works spectacularly, but I do not understand how. I can't provide the exact query, but here's an approximation:

```sql
with a as (

    select
         dt.[Date]
        ,p.product_no
        ,[date_start] = cast( RIGHT( MIN( RIGHT( '000000' + cast( p.price as varchar ), 6) + convert( varchar, p.date_start, 112 ) ), 8 ) as date )
        ,[date_expire] = cast( RIGHT( MIN( RIGHT( '000000' + cast( p.price as varchar ), 6) + convert( varchar, isnull(p.date_expire,'1/1/9999'), 112 ) ), 8 ) as date )
        ,[price] = MIN(p.price)
    from pricing p with (nolock) 
        inner join datetable dt with (nolock) on dt.[Date] between p.date_start and isnull(p.date_expire,getDate())
    group by 
         dt.[Date]
        ,p.product_no

), b as (

    select distinct
         a.date
        ,a.product_no
        ,[date_start] = iif( isnull(LAG(a.price) OVER (PARTITION BY a.product_no ORDER BY a.date),-1) <> a.price, a.date, null )
        ,[date_expire] = iif( isnull(LEAD(a.price) OVER (PARTITION BY a.product_no ORDER BY a.date),-1) <> a.price, a.date, null )
        ,a.price
    from a

)

select distinct
     b.product_no
    ,[date_start] = coalesce( b.date_start, LAG(b.date_start) OVER (PARTITION BY b.product_no ORDER BY b.date) )
    ,[date_expire] = coalesce( b.date_expire, nullif(LEAD(b.date_expire) OVER (PARTITION BY b.product_no ORDER BY b.date), cast( getDate() as date ) ) )
    ,b.price
from b
where b.date_start is not null
   or ( b.date_expire is not null 
        and b.date_expire <> cast( getDate() as date ) )
order by 1,2;
```

This pricing table includes prices for a couple hundred products over 12 years or so and, many times, there are multiple prices active at the same time. These may overlap completely or partially. What I'm trying to do is create a clean table showing the lowest price at any given point in time. I seem to have succeeded.

What I don't understand is this: if you run the definition of `a`, that first select, it produces millions of rows. So many, in fact, that I've never let it run all the way through. It was clearly well on its way to taking a long time and eating up tons of memory. If I run the whole thing, though? That takes about 25 seconds and produces, as you would expect, only a few thousand rows.

So how does SQL Server pull this off? It's clearly not executing each step in its entirety then moving on to the next step. I wish to understand this voodoo. If this goes some way toward helping me understand when a CTE would be faster than a series of temp tables and vice versa, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you reviewed the execution plan? Turn on `include actual execution plan` in SSMS and then run it, and review the output. Then run just the first query as you mentioned and review that output plan. What is different?

Comment: SQL Server executes the *entire* query, not individual parts. If the *entire* query affects only a few dozen rows, the tables have proper indexes and the CTEs/subqueries don't have expressions that prevent the use of indexes, SQL Server will create an execution plan that's as fast as possible. If one side of the join generates 5M rows and the other just 5, SQL Server will try to find the 5 matching rows in the 5M

Comment: I'm very reluctant to run the first select all the way through, though I guess I can try it on the test server and see whether it ever finishes.
---------
Turns out it wasn't so bad. 8.9m rows in 58 seconds. I'll be honest, though, these query plans are a little opaque to me.

Comment: BTW `with (nolock)` doesn't mean `go fast`, quite the opposite. It means `read dirty or duplicate data while throwing from time to time`. It's *not* a way to improve performance

Comment: @volfied `see whether it ever finishes` that doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is the execution plan. The entire query is *not* the same as the 25M-row part. SQL Server won't execute that part first, then the others. It will check for any indexes, check the data statistics and start from the *smallest* table if that results in faster execution. Check the estimated execution plan of the entire query vs the execution plan of the big subquery.

Comment: @volfied There is also an option to provide an estimated execution plan instead of the actual run which involves running the whole query.

Comment: Understood about `with (nolock)`. It's convention at the office because we don't want to hold up other people's queries. We're kind of a small shop and the risk of data integrity problems during reporting queries is minimal. At least that's how it's been explained to me.

Comment: `and b.date_expire <> cast( getDate() as date )`     Why `<>` ?  Do you really expect `date_expire` to go past the current date ? (This will give you another 20 ns gain in speed )

Comment: @Luuk I was getting records for both date_expire = null and date_expire = getDate(). That clause took care of the problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is SQL Server clever enough to do that if I turned this into a series of temp tables, as well? Or is that the advantage of using CTEs in a nutshell?

Comment: `It's convention at the office` that's not what you're doing. You're doing the exact opposite, taking a Schema-Stability lock on the table. You avoid delays for your query because you ignore locked **and dirty, and duplicate rows**. The reason you'll get exceptions is because your query will actually see rows while they're bein moved around. If you're "lucky" you'll see the same row twice. If you're unlucky, you'll see the data pages while they're being moved, resulting in errors

Comment: Funniest thing about "not holding up other queries" is that it isn't even the best solution for that. The best solution is to just use `SNAPSHOT` isolation. And if you were doing it for performance then you should use `TABLOCK` and block the whole table.

Comment: Either way, please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. And please show the tables and index definitions. This question is not answerable otherwise. Also I refuse to believe that `a` produces millions of rows, and `b` does not. They are both grouping over `product_no, date`, so there should be the same number of rows (ergo the `distinct` is a waste of time).

Comment: "Is SQL Server clever enough to do that if I turned this into a series of temp tables, as well? Or is that the advantage of using CTEs in a nutshell?" Its the advantage and disadvantage of using a CTE... a CTE will generate a single execution plan, in some cases, like yours, that works well. In many cases, where the CTE gets too complex, performance gets worse, and in such cases it can be advantageous to use intermediate temp tables, because that materialises the results and splits the query into multiple execution plans.

Comment: Like everything SQL the answer is "it depends" - you have a bunch of SQL tools in your toolbox and they all have their pros and cons. The specific situation will determine which is the best tool.

Comment: And note, the query itself doesn't tell you have the engine executes it, which is why its important to learn to read execution plans to find out how the engine translated your query into an execution plan. Table definitions, index definitions, statistics, all plan a part in how a query performs.

Comment: My two cents: 1. SQL language is a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) meaning you tell it what results you want and it figures out how to get them. This is why query tuning in SQL Server can be a bit of black magic 2. It actually takes a non trivial amount of time to transmit results to the client (SSMS or something else), so a trivial query returning millions of rows will take longer time to return/display results, then for these results to be further processed by other queries, which end up returning a few thousands of rows.

Comment: [Continued] "Results To Text" is the fastest way to display results in SSMS.

Comment: @Charlieface oh, b definitely produces millions of rows. It's the final output that's only thousands.

Comment: As for `with (nolock)`, this conversation, combined with a chat with our new junior DBA has convinced me that it's bad practice, office policy notwithstanding. Moreover, I understand why. I'll definitely be changing my ways and even advocating for a change in policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a declarative, not a procedural, language. When you use a CTE as part of declaring what you want, you are not writing a procedure to get your result. The server's query planner, in your query's case, notices that the `date_start` and `date_expire` columns you use for filtering your final result refer back to columns in your original table. It filters the original table, not the generated result of the CTE.

Query planner optimization software is the result of decades of work by thousands of very smart programmers. It does some amazing things in figuring out clever ways to access tables.

For many of us, SQL is the first declarative language we encounter. We're used to describing the result we want by telling the computer how to get it. But we need a different mindset for SQL.

The comments to your question talk about ways to understand what the query plan does for a particular query. If a query is too slow for your app, you can dig into the plan and figure out how to persuade your server to use a faster plan. That often involves adding an index.

Read Marcus Winand's e-book https://use-the-index-luke.com/ to expand your understanding of all this.

Comment: Thank you, O. Jones. I think this not only explains why my particular case was faster in its entirety, but also what sort of circumstances to look for when choosing a temp table vs a CTE. I'll check out the eBook sometime soon.

Comment: In most cases using a temp table is a last resort. Query planners can "materialize" a CTE when necessary. That is, they can create internal temp tables. In SQL server's query plans, the word "spool" hints at a materialized result.

Comment: Interesting. I've had at least one occasion where the same query as a series of temp tables was much faster than a series of CTEs. I wonder what was different about that time.